# Change values (colors) of TextView with a button click

Tags: android, android-button, textcolor

So I'm trying to make this EditText to go from a textColor to another when I hit that specific button (for instance: button1 change the textcolor to BLUE, button2 change it to GREEN etc.)

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_test"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/colorBtn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/colorBtn"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/colorBtn"
    android:id="@+id/colorBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="changeColor"/>
```

How should I have to proceed? :\

Comment: Look into `OnClickListeners`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate your button to set more than one color

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/colorBtn"
    android:id="@+id/colorBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="changeColor"
/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/colorBtnRed"
    android:id="@+id/colorBtnRed"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="changeColor"
/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/colorBtnGreen"
    android:id="@+id/colorBtnGreen"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="changeColor"
/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/colorBtnBlue"
    android:id="@+id/colorBtnBlue"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="changeColor"
/>
```

In your changeColor, check the button id. If it is the colorButtonBlue id, then set the text color of your EditText to blue. If it is colorButtonRed, ther set to red abd so on...

```
public void changeColor(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.colorBtnRed:
            edtTest.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case R.id.colorBtnGreen:
            edtTest.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case R.id.colorBtnBlue:
            edtTest.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;
        default:
            edtTest.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Of course, in your Declaration section, do this:

```
EditText edtTest = null;
```

And in your onCreate do something like this (after the super and setContentVieew lines):

```
edtTest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.test);
```

Comment: OK maybe i got it! One last thing: what I have to do with that editText1? It is supposed to be my textview, so how I could link these?

Comment: You named an EditText (and an EditText is shown in the layout), not a TextView: `So I'm trying to make this EditText to go from a textColor to another`... but you an easily change from editText1 to textView1 in the code shown.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still new into this! eheh. So, I've got that EditText in the layout, and that editText1 in MainActivity.. I mean, aren't they the same object? Because when I copy the code you wrote before in Java, it give me editText1 as an error :| So sorry for being boring!

Comment: Yes they are... it depends on how you named them... edtTest or editText1, or whatever: the names must me the same. I just addded my EDIT with the EditText named differently from the example - just because of hurry (doing other 12 things in the meanwhile). I'll edit my example to match **edtTest** (I like this pseudo-hungarian naming) - OK, done.

Comment: OMG it actually worked! Thank you so much! It was very important for me to get how to make this work! (For the naming: ahahahah!!)

Comment: May I ask the downvoter the reason for downvoting? If the answer has been accepted, I think it doesn't deserve a -1.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? -

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            editText1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }
                    }););
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new into this :S
Do I have to import the button1? Or I just have to replace it with my button id? Same thing for editText1 so? Thank you! :))

Comment: you have to replace button1 and editText1 with your project names... but first you have to assing the reference to the view to them using code like this: Button greenBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);